# Unable to activate Anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I'm successfully running `Anaconda2` on the base environment, however i couldn't activate `py27 env`. I had tried to run the same command on `Anaconda prompt` ,`cmd` and `Powershell` (as administrator) but i am still getting the same following error:

```
C:\Users\kr.DOMAIN\Desktop\DeepConvSep-master\examples>activate py27
'@CALL "D:\Anaconda\Library\bin\..\..\Scripts\conda.exe" shell.cmd.exe activate
activate py27' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

***echo %PATH%*** returns:

```
    C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microso
ft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\cygwin64\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\120\Tools\Binn\;G:\KR\MinGW\bin;G:\KR\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;G:\KR\MinGW\ming
w32\bin;G:\KR\MinGW\.p2\pool\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020\bin;C:\c
ygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mi
crosoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Windows\S
ysWOW64;C:\Windows\System32;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;D:\Anaconda\bin;D:\A
naconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Users\kr.DOMAIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyt
hon36\Scripts\;C:\Users\kr.DOMAIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Use
rs\kr.DOMAIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\kr.DOMA
IN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does 'echo %PATH%' return?

Comment: @O.Suleiman i have edited my post please check it back, and thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you check if there is any file called 'activate.bat' in your 'D:\Anaconda\Scripts'?

Comment: yes @O.Suleiman it exists

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new environment first

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Then activate it through Anaconda prompt using

```
activate myenv
```

Then verify using

```
python --version
```

Comment: thanks @Samer, i have already created py27 environment, and to confirm that i tried the **create command** again and i ended up with the following message: "CondaValueError: prefix already exists: D:\Anaconda\envs\py27"

Comment: kindly try `$ source activate py27` in the cmd prompt terminal

Comment: sorry, scratch the `$ source` part...that's for Mac/Linux...just try `activate py27` in the cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have problems with your environment variables since it seems that you have installed many versions of python before installing using anaconda.

Therefore,  you have 2 possible solutions, you can either uninstall all other pythons installed and clean your environment then reinstall using anaconda since having many python versions will cause you so much headache, or, if you want a fast solution, you can always make `cmd` see the `activate` script by running the following lines on `cmd`:

```
D:    
cd D:\Anaconda\Scripts 
activate.bat py27
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't know what actually was the reason behind the error, i tried every possible solution i found on the web but none worked for me.

I know that this is not a suitable solution for most of others facing the same issue, however **I solved the problem by installing a fresh copy of windows 7** professional and the installing Anaconda, I think trying to install and remove Anaconda multiple times during the error fixing process made that somehow.

Anyway, Thanks for contributers.